# Dependency injection with abstract class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am struggling for last two days to get a grip of DI.

I have two problems:

1. If I have a some common functionality why I can't do the same thing implementing DI with an abstract class?
2. In my example I have many class instance created under writefile, so should I move out all object creation from there? What if I have a layered design? Should these classes be passed all along?

   ```
   public interface IWriteFile
   {
       void write();
   }

   public class WriteXMLFile : IWriteFile
   {    
       public void write()
       {

       }
   }

   public class writefile
   {
       IWriteFile _file;

       public writefile(IWriteFile file)
       {
           _file = file;
       }

       public void WriteMyFile()
       {
           _file.write();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: For your second question, does `writefile` have many different types of objects it uses to get its work done? Or do you just have many instances of a few types?

Comment: @Jeff Bridgman writefile is having many type of objects it uses to get its work done.

Comment: I'm not sure where your doubt is. 1- You should always program to interfaces, not only when doing DI. But you can have an abstract class implementing the interface, and your injected type inheriting from the abstract class.

Comment: 2- Your injected type can also have injected types, and they should never build the type themselves. You should let your DI container build the object tree. In more complex scenarios, you can mix DI with other creational patterns, like an abstract factory or a builder. But it is the container that call these creational classes, not a domain type.

Comment: If what I wrote was not what you wanted, please clarify where you're struggling. Since you also program in C#, I'd like to recommend the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://manning.com/seemann/). It's where I began with DI, with no previous experience in it, and found the book very easy to follow. DI is not hard after you get the grasp of it, although can be confusing at first.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Regarding your first point:

Let's say you want to test something that uses your abstract class. If you're directly using an abstract class, then if you want to do something different in the shared functionality in the common class, there's not much you can do.

With an interface, you've broken the coupling with the dependency. This is what the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) is talking about when it says "High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions". Your class shouldn't depend on the lower-level class (even if it's an abstract class) to get its work done. Both the lower-level and higher-level class should depend on the interface which defines how they are going to interact. Using an interface helps separate the two, giving you [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). Something else can handle wiring them together.

#### Regarding your second point:

Powerful DI frameworks actually handle a lot of this complexity for you.

Let's say you have a class - `Thing` - that has a bunch of dependencies.

```
public Thing(
    IThingRepository repository, 
    IEmailer emailer, 
    ILogger logger, 
    INeedMoreStuff stuff
) : IThing
```

When you set up your IoC container, you'd do something like the following to associate which implementation to use for each interface:

```
IoC.Register<MySqlThingRepository>().As<IThingRepository>();
IoC.Register<MicrosoftExchangeEmailer>().As<IEmailer>();
IoC.Register<TruncatingFileLogger>().As<ILogger>();
IoC.Register<MoreStuff>().As<INeedMoreStuff>();
IoC.Register<Thing>().As<IThing>();
```

Then you can simply do:

```
IThing thing = IoC.Resolve<IThing>();
```

These fancy frameworks handle getting all the dependencies for you (since you told it how to get them) and will construct a `Thing` for you.

That being said, sometimes a fancy framework like that is overkill. In those cases, I usually use the [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) to abstract out the details of creating an object while still making sure the object being created follows good DI principles like constructor injection of its dependencies.

#### Regarding your polymorphism and interfaces:

Someone [described](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PolyMorphism) polymorphism as simply "Same interface, different implementation. Substitutability". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) defines it as "the provision of a single interface to entities of different types". According to those definitions, I think using interfaces doesn't go against polymorphism. I feel in C# interfaces are usually sufficient for providing different implementations of the same "interface".

Yes, you can use an abstract base class to do the same thing, but I'd *only* use that if there's a common set of functionality I can factor out into the base class to keep my code [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself).

#### Regarding multiple implementations for an interface with StructureMap

I don't how StructureMap handles this, but presumably there's some logic that will decide when you want to use `Thing1` versus `Things2`. You might be able to provide a delegate to StructureMap that it can use to get an `IThing` which would contain that logic.

Alternatively, you can have a factory that takes some parameters and decides which `IThing` to return. There are situations where I've put an interface on my factory and constructor injected that, or alternatively have the factory creating the object using `IThing` use the `ThingFactory` to get the right one.

Comment: Thamks. That was really helpful.But i still have one Question..We would be using structureMap to implement DI.So just going by your examlpe if i have Thing1 and Thing2 both inheriting Ithing will this work.Also if there needs to be a seperate Iterface for each dependency aren't we moving away from polymorphic behaviour.I dont know if i am making any sence but still...

Comment: I've edited my answer with replies to your comment, however it's getting a bit too broad. If you have further questions, it probably would be good to break that out into its own specific question, since overly-broad question are off-topic for StackOverflow. See [ask] and the [help/on-topic] in general.

Comment: Excellent answer, one of the best I've seen on DI in general